# Как удалить запись в бд с помощью hibernate

Tags: java, база-данных, hibernate

Есть свой crud repository:

```
public interface HashDBA extends CrudRepository<Hash, String> {
    List<Hash> findByHash(String hash);
    void deleteByHash(String hash);
}
```

Функция deleteByHash(), должна удалять строку с определенным hash. После выполнения команды:

```
hashDBA.deleteByHash(hash);
```

Ничего не происходит. Как правильно удалять записи из БД с помощью hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

Решением была команда: `hashDBA.delete(hashList.get(0));`